# How To Change Value Of Particular Signal For Different Test Case Using Capl

Tags: testing, capl, canoe

In CANoe configuration my node is sending msg1 continuously, I am using that message in my test case, written in CANoe Test module. But for different test cases I want different values of that signal. As that signal must need to be sent continuously from that node itself. How should I change the value of signal for every test case.

Comment: Are you using an Interaction layer to send the message or a timer?

Answer (score 1):

For the signal value change you can use two methods:

1. Simple assignment:

   $mySignal = value;
2. Dedicated function:

   setSignal(mySignal, value);

Difference is that in second case there will be corresponding info about value set in the final report.

Answer (score 0):

Using a IL (interactive layer) will help you send this message continuously. This message by default takes the value which is defined in database if a database is attached. Now what you have to do is to create different CAPL test modules which will act as your different test cases. When you update that signal from your testmodule the signal will take that latest value and transmit on bus. For next test case update a different value.

For sending signal when IL is used use below syntax,
$Signal = value;